# How to create store procedure for this MySQL query which I want to call in java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

***mysql***

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(SELECT ssn, superssn, 0 as depth from 
EMPLOYEE where ssn='888665555' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT A.SSN, A.SUPERSSN, depth + 1 FROM 
EMPLOYEE A INNER JOIN CTE WHERE 
A.SUPERSSN = CTE.SSN ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

I tried many ways but it was wrong so I request some help.
See my sql code and give some advice?

***the tables***

```
mysql> select ssn,superssn from EMPLOYEE;
+-----------+-----------+
| ssn       | superssn  |
+-----------+-----------+
| 888665555 | NULL      |
| 000000002 | 000000001 |
| 000000003 | 000000002 |
| 000000004 | 000000003 |
| 000000005 | 000000004 |
| 000000006 | 000000005 |
| 123456789 | 333445555 |
| 453453453 | 333445555 |
| 666884444 | 333445555 |
| 333445555 | 888665555 |
| 987654321 | 888665555 |
| 987987987 | 987654321 |
| 999887777 | 987654321 |
| 000000001 | 999887777 |
+-----------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the table so when you help me you could refer.

Comment: Do other store procedures work for you, or is this a generic answer about using store procedures? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: this is for me 
also i tried many time to get right answer 
ex)

    create PROCEDURE curdemo() begin DECLARE done int DEFAULT 
    FALSE; DECLRAE a CHAR(20); DECLARE b CHARE(20); DECLARE c 
    INT; DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ssn FROM EMPLOYEE; 
    DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT superssn FROM EMPLOYEE; 
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 
    TRUE; Open cur1; Open cur2; Read_loop: LOOP FETCH cur1 into a; 
    FETCH cur2 into b; If done then LEAVE read_loop; END IF; If a == b 
    THEN c+=1; END IF; END LOOP; Close cur1; Close cur2; End;
but it doens't work

Comment: Please include the additional info in your post, and define "doesn't work" (usually there is an error message, or something works differently from the expectation etc.)

Comment: Ignoring the obvious typos null safe equal in mysql is <=> (not ==) and you need to use a set verb to increment a variable (set c = c + 1). You possibly are not setting delimiters either.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html